Having some issue when importing some components to page.tsx (Next.JS)
Im quite new at NextJS and I have a problem when I want to import my components which giving me a message that says "Cannot find module '@/Components/NavBar' or its corresponding type declarations" even I already tried to write the directory correctly.
Any solution will be appriciated, thank you.
So here's my 'NavBar" components which the components folder itself is outside the src\app folder
import React from "react";
export const NavBar = () => {
  return(
    <nav className="bg-white shadow-gray-300 w-100 px-8 ">
      <div className="py-2 px-4 container flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap ">
        <div className="text-main order-1  flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap gap-4">
          
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" className="h-10 w-10 order-1" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            stroke="currentColor">
            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" strokeWidth="2"
              d="M9 3v2m6-2v2M9 19v2m6-2v2M5 9H3m2 6H3m18-6h-2m2 6h-2M7 19h10a2 2 0 002-2V7a2 2 0 00-2-2H7a2 2 0 00-2 2v10a2 2 0 002 2zM9 9h6v6H9V9z"/>
          </svg>

          <h1 className="order-2 font-semibold">Klinik Psikologi Sejahtera</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="order-2 gap-10 flex items-center justify-between flex-wrap text-sm font-thin text-main">
          <div className=" hover:text-gray-700"><a href="#">Beranda</a></div>
          <div className=" hover:text-gray-700"><a href="#">Jadwal</a></div>
          <button className="px-4 py-2 bg-main hover:bg-gray-700 text-sm text-gray-50 rounded-full flex items-center gap-2">
              Log in
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  )
}

And here's my page.tsx code:
import {NavBar} from '@/Components/NavBar';

export default function Home() {
  return(
    <><NavBar />
        <div className="min-w-full h-auto py-10 pb-16 px-10 md:px-20 bg-gradient-to-b from-bg to-white flex-row items-start justify-center text-main">
            <div className="flex-row justify-center items-center my-10 mb-16">
                <p className="color:#015C92;">Menuju kesehatan Mental yang Lebih Baik</p>
                <h1 className="font-semibold text-4xl text-center my-6">Selamat Datang di Klinik Psikologi Sejahtera</h1>
                <p className="color:#015C92;">Di Klinik Psikologi Sejahtera, kami menawarkan layanan konsultasi psikologi profesional yang dapat Anda pesan sesuai kebutuhan. Platform kami memungkinkan Anda untuk menjadwalkan sesu, melihat profil psikolog, dan menerima pengingat untuk pengalaman yang lebih nyaman.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

And yes, the page.tsx file is inside src\app

Can you try moving the navbar file inside the src folder (next to app folder), This might solve the issue

Do the following checks, maybe this will sort it out:

Case Sensitivity: Make sure your folder is actually named components (all lowercase). If it’s named components but you’re importing it as @/Components/NavBar (with a capital C), that will break. Try updating your import to:
import { NavBar } from "@/components/NavBar"; // lowercase "components"


Check Your tsconfig.json: If you're using the @ alias, check your tsconfig.json file to make sure it includes this under compilerOptions:
"paths": {
  "@/*": ["./*"]
}

This configuration ensures TypeScript can resolve paths starting with @/. If it’s not there, add it, save, and restart your TypeScript server. (In VS Code, press Ctrl+Shift+P and search for TypeScript: Restart TS Server.)

File Location: Double-check that NavBar.tsx exists exactly where you’re pointing to. It should be inside a folder named components at the root (or wherever your alias resolves). Also, make sure there are no typos in the file name, and it’s using the correct extension (.tsx or .js).

Clear the Cache: If everything looks fine and it’s still not working, try restarting your Next.js server and clearing the cache. Run:
npm run dev -- --reset-cache



Hopefully, one of these steps fixes the issue! Let me know how it goes! 
